# Google Auth in Firebase Angular 10

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm trying to use Google as a third party authentication method but I'm getting this telling me auth doesn't exist. Any suggestions

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import '@firebase/auth';
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
   constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore, 
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {    
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }
 GoogleAuth() {
  return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth providers are included in 'Firebase/app'. currently in your imports you have:

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
```

Based on that, you should be able to access the GoogleAuthProvider by using:

```
return this.AuthLogin(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import the proper auth instance from firebase. try importing the below it will work.

```
import {auth} from 'firebase'
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Module '"../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. Did you mean to use 'import auth from "../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?"

Comment: no that's because you are not importing the auth module instance. import from the above module sort the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have an older firebase version. Try this:

import firebase from 'firebase/app';

and then....

new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider() should give you the provider